# How to set shipping cost using live rates based on cart subtotal

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods

I am having a hard time trying to create a coupon code that will set the shipping rate to $10.95 if the cart subtotal is $150 while using USPS and FedEx live rates.

I can see that there is an option to apply the discount to the shipping cost, but since it is a variable rate, there is no fixed amount or percent that I can specify that will bring the shipping cost to exactly $10.95.

Is there any way to create this shipping rule?

I am using Magento CE 1.9. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite class `Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping` and apply your logic in the method `collectRates` like

```
    $oldRates = $result->getAllRates();

    $result->reset();
    foreach ($oldRates as $rate){
        if($someConditionHere){
            $rate->setPrice(10.95);
        }
        $result->append($rate);
    }
```

There are also some extensions at the magento connect that can create *Shipping Rules* by special condition or coupon.